# Any way to upload exception logs thrown by Android to Server

Tags: android, logging

Is there any way to upload exception logs thrown by Android to Server ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ACRA](http://acra.ch) or [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com).

Comment: Thanks Guys, ACRA looks more promising as an open source project

Answer (score 2):

You can view the brief report in "Exception/ANR" from Google Play Store

It is also suggested to use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

It is very easy to use, and able to record all uncaught exception by setting a value to true in XML

Answer (score 0):

[Crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com/) will do what you need without having to do it complex way. Just download the library, and integrate it.

It is easy to integrate, and much more reliable as compared to Google Play Store. Crittercism catches all exceptions, thread stack (so that u can check if there are any threads waiting doing nothing) and also the type of device. As compared to Play Store that just has a mention of about 1% of my crashes.

Google Analytics on the other hand is much more heavy as compared to flurry. I recommend a combination of flurry and crittercism.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a third party lib, you can catch the exceptions yourself and do whatever you want with them like this -

```
UncaughtExceptionHandler currentHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        // Register if not already registered
        if (!(currentHandler instanceof ExceptionHandler)) {
            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this, currentHandler));
        }
```

Do this in the Application class.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, Google officially supporting `Fabrics's crashlytics` online tool with `Firebase` for managing crash related informations. Also we can upload any exception to the server.

Also they provide a dashboard for visualizing many things related to our app.